# What is the value of the static variable declared inside a function?

Tags: c++, function, static

A static integer variable is declared inside a function.  The variable increments by 1 when the function is called.  The function is called and returns 3 times.  What is the value of the variable on the third function call and what is the value when it returns?

Comment: Please show your function/code.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int foo();
int main(){
int a;

a=foo();
a=foo();
cout<< a <<endl;
a=foo();
cout<< a;
 return 0;
}
int foo() {
   static int x;
   x++;
   //cout<< x;
   return x;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int foo() {
   static int x = 0;
   x++;
   return x;
}
```

The keyword `static` acts to extend the lifetime of a variable to the lifetime of the program; e.g. initialization occurs once and once only and then the variable retains its value - whatever it has come to be - over all future calls to foo().

Answer (score 0):

When we declare a member of a class as static it means no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the static member. A static member is shared by all objects of the class.

so it will return 3 if the its value start with 0